# How to bind two input field in one span

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I want to make a form for user that can fill in their first name and second name.

I want to use angularjs. But I don't know how to bind two different input to one line. 
I tried this code without any success.

```
<form data-ng-app="">
   Voornaam: <input type="text" name="firstname" data-ng-model='name1'><br>
   Achternaam: <input type="text" name="lastname" data-ng-model='name2'><br>
   <h4>Name: <span style=" text-transform: capitalize;"  data-ng-bind='name1; name2'  ng-trim='false'> </span></h4>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<h4>Name: <span style="text-transform: capitalize" data-ng-bind="name1 + ' ' +  name2" data-ng-trim="false"> </span></h4>
```

`ng-bind` must contain an Angular expression (optionally you can add an Angular filter after the '|' delimiter).

[Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following
>   differences:
>
> - Context: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global    window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
> - Forgiving: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties    generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression
>     evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.
> - No Control Flow Statements: you cannot use the following in an    Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
> - Filters: You can use filters within expressions to format data before    displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form data-ng-app="">
   Voornaam: <input type="text" name="firstname" data-ng-model='name1'><br>
   Achternaam: <input type="text" name="lastname" data-ng-model='name2'><br>
   <h4>Name: <span style=" text-transform: capitalize;" ng-bind='name1'> </span> -<span style=" text-transform: capitalize;" ng-bind='name2'> </span></h4>
</form>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, because it uses two span elements.